Which is better for Dynamic querying String Builder or string buffer?
I am dynamically building SQL queries in Java using JDBC and need to determine the best approach for handling these queries efficiently.
Currently, I am debating between using StringBuilder or StringBuffer for constructing the queries. I understand that StringBuffer is synchronized and thread-safe, while StringBuilder is not.
The application generates multiple queries based on user input.
Queries might involve conditions, joins, and subqueries, so the query building process can be dynamic and complex.

Use StringBuilder. I never understood why StringBuffer is synchronised, its not common to share it between threads. The typical usage of both classes even in multi-threaded apps is by single thread access using a not-shared local variable, so there is no difference in outputs.

Nevertheless use a PreparedStatement with parameters, in order to do the text escapes in SQL and again SQL injection (your mention of user input). Also consider JPA/CriteriaBuilder.

"The application generates multiple queries based on user input." ==> beware of Little Bobby Tables!  || do you need it to be "thread-safe"? yes -> StringBuffer; no -> StringBuilder

There is not really ever a good reason to use StringBuffer, period.

Looks definitely like a StringBuilder usage to me. The thread-safe StringBuffer is useful when multiple threads are putting data into the same instance of StringBuffer, which doesn't make sense for SQL query building.
